# How does a browser interpret a page with no charset in the response header or meta tag?

Tags: html, apache, character-encoding, browser

I installed xampp 1.8.1 for Windows and I opened `http://localhost/xampp` which opens the index page for xampp.

The response header for the page for the content type doesn't specify a Charset:

```
Content-Type:text/html
```

The page's html doesn't specify a Charset also.

How does a browser handle the page in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the page starts with a UTF-8 or UTF-16 Byte order mark, then the encoding is taken from that. This happens before and in preference to looking at the HTTP header and the `<meta>` elements.

If there's no BOM either, then the encoding used is implementation dependent and may well depend on where in the world the user happens to be.

All the variants at that stage are effectively consistent with ASCII though, so if the content of the page contains only ASCII characters, there's probably no harm done in not specify an encoding.

See http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding for the precise details.

Comment: Re 3rd paragraph of the answer, HTML5 CR says about [declaring encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#charset): “A character encoding declaration is required (either in the Content-Type metadata or explicitly in the file) even if the encoding is US-ASCII, because a character encoding is needed to process non-ASCII characters entered by the user in forms, in URLs generated by scripts, and so forth.” For example, your page might be all ASCII, but what happens when someone types “é” in a form on the page?

Answer (score 1):

If no charset is found then it will read some amount of the HTML code from the page and then try to guess the encoding. If it cannot figure it out then it will default to the browser's default character set. Depending on the browser it will often be something like Windows-1252 (a superset of Latin-1 also called ISO 8859-1) or UTF-8.

It is important that you set the character set yourself. There are vulnerabilities (at least in older versions of IE) where you can feed the browser malicious code that will run if the browser guesses wrongly or uses its default charset.

Setting it in an HTTP header should always be done, and setting it in the HTML never hurts.

Setting it as a header is usually done by the server. In Apache it is usually done in the httpd.conf file, but it can also be done in an .htaccess file:

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .php .html .css .js
```

... but it can also be done in PHP:

```
header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8');
```

In HTML you can set it like this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

That is the HTML5 way of doing it, but older browsers understand it quite well.